# div overlapping footer despite of style="clear:both"?

Tags: css, templates, html, joomla

I am writing my own template for joomla 2.5.6. I am not sure if this issue is Joomla or simply css related.

The template is simple, it has a sidebar on the left and content on the right, and a footer. Now when the content is short and there are several modules on the sidebar, the modules overlap the footer.

It looks like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/screenshotmdph.jpg/

The html from index.php looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container_6">
    <div class="grid_6 header">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>" title=""><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/assets/images/logo.png" alt="home" id="logo"/></a>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container_6">
    <div class="grid_6 head_logo">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header_logo" />
        <div class="left_menu">
            <div class="left_menu_content">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left_menu" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right_module">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" />
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container_6">
    <div class="grid_6">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content_holder">
                <!-- beginn content -->
                <div class="container_6">
                    <div class="content_component">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" />
                        <jdoc:include type="component" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="container_6">
    <div class="grid_6">
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used the 960-grid system which has the class clear on it, but the other classes are defined here:

```
    .header {
 background: url('../images/top.png') no-repeat;
 height:93px;
 width:100%;
}

.head_logo {
    background: url('../images/shadow.png') repeat-y;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:12px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}
.left_menu {
    background: url('../images/menuBg.png') no-repeat;
    width:284px;
    min-height:611px;
    top:300px;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
}
.right_module {
    width:180px;
    height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
    top:300px;
    left:730px;
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
}

.content {
    background: url('../images/shadow.png') repeat-y;
    min-height:500px;

}
.content_holder {
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
    width:960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height:500px;
}

.content_component {
    width:666px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 284px;
    margin:0 5px;
}

#logo {
    margin:15px 0 0 25px;
    float:left;
}

.footer{
    background: url('../images/bottom.png') no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:92px;
}
```

I am lost with this, because it should work because of the clearing class above the footer, but it doesn't.. Unfortunatedly I have no online example, its all local

Anybody an idea how I could find the error? Thank you so much

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Sorry, I forgot, the

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Is defined in the grid.css, and looks like this:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

I edited the question title also, sorry was wrong

**Addition!!**

I wanted to add a screenshot of the problem. Please look here:

http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/jegt-i-6f49-jpg.html

You see, the .left-menu is positioned with absolute and begins inside the .head-logo class. The .left-menu should not go inside the purple footer.

**How can I tell the content divs to be equal in height with the left-menu?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `Clear:both` instead of `clear:all` which is not a style definition in MHO.

Comment: Thank you, this was my error, I am not using clear:all, I use the clear class defined from the 960-grid system. I changed it in the question

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems, you may be placing the 'clear' div in a wrong place, but it's hard to say, not seeing the actual page with all the css attached, including the grid ones. Maybe you would be able to actually generate the page, save to your local disk and put it online?

Comment: Thank you! I think I know where the problem is. The css is build now that the left-menu is generated in the div with the header image, because it has to overlap the header image. The content is created in the div below, so there is no way to tell the parent-div to clear the floating, because the left menu and the content has different parend divs... So  my problem is the basic setting of the site. But I cannot change the parent divs, because I need the menu to overlap the upper parent... hmmm

Comment: I would be happy if anybody has ideas to it... I tried to add another div as a container which could be cleared and thus tell the footer where to begin, but it does not help...

Comment: I added a screenshot to my posting which explains the problem. I would be very happy if anybody could help with it